# Не завершаются последние потоки multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import requests
import random
import time

def func_main(thr):
    time1 = time.time()
    while True:
        proxy_line = proxy_lines[random.randint(1, len(proxy_lines)-1)].strip()
        session = requests.session()
        session.temeout = (5 , 5)
        Adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections = 1, pool_maxsize = 0, max_retries = 0)
        session.mount('http://', Adapter)
        session.mount('https://', Adapter)
        session.proxies = {
            'http' : proxy_line,
            'https' : proxy_line
        }
        try:
            request = session.post('http://www.yahex.ru/')
            request.close() 
            break
        except Exception as exception:
            #print(exception)
            #print('Thread #' + str(thr + 1) + '|Reconnect|')
            pass
    time2 = time.time() - time1
    global thr_quantity
    thr_quantity = thr_quantity - 1
    print('Thread #' + str(thr + 1) + ' завершил работу|Прокси:' + proxy_line + '|Активных потоков:' + str(thr_quantity) + '|Время выполнения:{:.3f}'.format(time2))
    return()
#*******************************************************************#
with open('C:\\proxy.txt' , 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as proxy_file:
    proxy_lines = proxy_file.readlines()


class Profiler(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._startTime = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("*************************\nВремя выполнения программы : {:.3f} sec".format(time.time() - self._startTime))

thr_quantity = 50   
    with Profiler() as p:
        with ThreadPool(thr_quantity) as pool:
            pool.map(func_main, range(thr_quantity))
            pool.close()
```

Проблема в следующем: запускаю код выше в 50 потоков, к примеру, 49 потоков выполняются, а на 50-ом потоке всё зависает и поток не выполняется. Либо на последнем виснет, либо на последних 10-ти потоках. Примерно так. Не могу понять в чем причина.
**На скриншоте ниже показана скорость выполнения потоков. Последний аж 10 минут чем то занимался. Но в большинстве случаев он не завершается.**
[image: Скорость выполнения последнего потока]

Comment: Хочу заметить, что без использования прокси, всё работает корректно, даже в 300 потоков. Только с использованием прокси ловлю залипание нескольких последних потоков.

Comment: какая операционная система? тут похоже на лимит tcp соединений

Comment: что происходит, если `session.temeout` на `session.timeout` заменить?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию в Windows установлен лимит на 20 tcp-соединений. От этого и получается dead-lock.

Обсуждение https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/18667011-c034-43bc-ab2e-0e87bf811e5e/windows-7-increase-the-limit-of-concurrent-tcp-connections-not-related-to-eula-file-sharing?forum=w7itpronetworking

На Linux ограничения конектов напрямую нет, но некоторые параметры влияют на их количество.

Обсуждение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux

Comment: Сделал как вы написали. Увы не помогло.

Comment: тоесть если ограничить число потоков до 16 - не помогает?

Comment: Почему именно 16? Я убрал ограничение, как вы подсказали. По сути зависание происходит независимо от количества потоков. Т.е. если я ставлю 20 или 300, в 95% случаев, последние пару потоков не завершают свою работу. Можете запусить код для теста. С одним прокси, либо без прокси все работает. Возможно не приходит ответ от прокси, с которому уже произошло подключение и это становится причиной залипания. Не могу понять, как это предотвратить, ведь requests.timeout, помогает лишь для первоначального соеденения. Если коннект к прокси состоялся, try except, как в моем случае, по ходу не спасает...

Comment: я намекал уменьшить количество конектов

Comment: а еще количество конектов может быть ограниченно на серверах

Comment: Сейчас попробую отфильтровать прокси предварительно, путем захода на нужный мне сайт в отдельной специально для этого созданной  программе.  Так же прикручу таймер на проверку соединения с прокси. Всё же подозреваю что подключение идет к тормазнутому прокси и поток бесконечно ждет ответа, в результате чего виснет.